# How do I get from Observable<BleHandler.BlePeripheral> to BleHandler.BlePeripheral?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rxbluetooth

I have a `variable` that gets me the type `Observable<BleHandler.BlePeripheral>` after using `flatMap` on the `array`.

```
let scannedPeripheral: Observable<BleHandler.BlePeripheral> = instance.bleScan()
            .flatMap{ Observable.from($0)}
```

But now I need to use that `variable` in another `function` that takes `BleHandler.BlePeripheral`:

```
instance.bleEstablishConnection(scannedPeripheral: scannedPeripheral)
```

Obviously it doesn't work. Is there a way to get my `Observable<BleHandler.BlePeripheral>` to just `BleHandler.BlePeripheral`

Comment: Does the `bleEstablishConnection(scannedPeripheral:)` method return something?

Comment: Yes it returns a `-> Observable<Any>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether or not the function returns a value and what type of value it returns...

If the function is void and you are just calling it for side effects then:

```
let disposable = scannedPeripheral
    .subscribe(onNext: { instance.bleEstablishConnection(scannedPeripheral: $0) })
```

If your function has side effects and returns an Observable then:

```
let returnValue = scannedPeripheral
    .flatMap { instance.bleEstablishConnection(scannedPeripheral: $0) }
```

If the function has no side effects and you are just calling it to transform your value into a different value then:

```
let returnValue = scannedPeripheral
    .map { instance.bleEstablishConnection(scannedPeripheral: $0) }
```

This last one is unlikely based on the name of the function, but I put it here for completeness.

Comment: Also, regarding `flatMap`, there are several different versions of the operator. Make sure you are using the appropriate one for your context: https://medium.com/@danielt1263/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c

Comment: Ah, nice, I did the second one and that worked. Thanks for the help @Daniel! I'll make sure to check out the link as well!